# How to install libusb?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, usb, libusb

I am having hard time installing libusb. I went across some YouTube videos, and they were talking about "INSTALLING" libusb. I went across another tutorial and they are saying we need to build it "manually". However, I downloaded libusb from http://sourceforge.net/projects/libusb-win32/files/.

In my download, there is no software to install (according to video, it is libusb_win32.exe).

My OS is Windows 7 Ultimate 32 bit. The PC is a Dell Inspiron 4030 (I need to install this in my desktop PC as well). The IDE is Qt, which works with the Visual Studio 2010 compiler.

How can I install this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet what you downloaded is a `.zip` file with no installer in it (probably named `libusb-win32-bin-1.2.6.0.zip`). The reason is that you don't have anything to install to have it work.

You only have to unzip it and then, add `libusb-win32-bin-1.2.6.0\include` to the include directories of your project using LibUSB. Then, you will have to add `libusb-win32-bin-1.2.6.0\lib\msvc` to the libraries used by your project. If you don't know how to do that [here is a useful link](http://blog.gockelhut.com/2009/11/visual-studio-2010-property-sheets-and.html) to have it work with MSVC 2010.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But after setting it up, I can't find any libsub.h file!

Comment: I mean, I can't find it in #include<>. It is not available in the machine as well.

Comment: @Soldier Are you sure you need it? What functions do you need? Are you sure they are not in `lusb0_usb.h` instead?

Comment: Yes, lusb0_usb.h is the solution. Thanks :)